# Where can I find the increased encounter O-power?

Tags: pokemon-x-y

I've heard that there is an O-power for increasing the Pokemon encounter rate but I don't know where to get this O-power.  How to obtain it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I advice you to take a look at [this](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/O-Power) article. In this article all O-Power's are listed with information about their power and where to obtain them.

Here a list of locations:

### O-Power

- Route 5 (Attack, Defense, HP, & Capture)
- Camphrier Hotel, second floor, far right room (Sp. Atk)
- Ambrette Hotel (Sp. Def)
- Cyllage Hotel (Prize Money)
- Geoseng Hotel (Speed)
- Shalour Pokemon Center (Critical)
- Cormarine Pokemon Center (Befriending)
- Lumiose Hotel Richissime, on North Blvd, between routes 16 and 14,
  near Hibernal Avenue (Bargain)
- **Laverre Pokemon Center (Encounter)**
- Dendemille Pokemon Center (Accuracy)
- Anistar Pokemon Center (Exp Point)
- Couriway Hotel (Stealth)
- Snowbelle Pokemon Center (PP Restoring)
- Lumiose Cafe Introversion, on South Blvd, between route 4 and 5, near
  Vernal Ave Max Style and all other O-powers required (Hatching)